# List is empty after getting data from firebase database

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have several points that I get from Firebase. I'm trying to add them to the list, but after adding the last log outputs an empty list

```
protected void readDataFromDB() {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("routes");

    myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        .....
            List<Point> pointList = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int i = 0; i < longitudeList.size(); i++) {
                pointList.add(new Point(latitudeList.get(i), longitudeList.get(i)));
            }

            List<Integer> listLengths = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DataSnapshot snapshots : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                int counter = 0;
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot1 : snapshots.getChildren()) {
                    counter += 1;
                }
                listLengths.add(counter);
            }

            List<Integer> chunkSizes = listLengths;
            int index = 0;
            for (int size : chunkSizes) {
                int endIndex = Math.min(index + size, pointList.size());
                twoDList.add(pointList.subList(index, endIndex));
                index = endIndex;
            }

        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w("TEST", "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
        }

    });
    Log.w("TEST", twoDList.toString());
}
```

What do I need to do so that the list is not empty?

Comment: Retrieving data from Firebase (and most cloud APIs) is asynchronous. It takes time to load this data, and to prevent blocking the app for the user, the loading happens off the main thread - while your main code continues to run. So your `Log.w("TEST", twoDList.toString()); }` happens before any of the `twoDList.add(pointList.subList(index, endIndex));` ever happened. To solve this, any code that needs the data has to be inside the `onDataChange`, be called from there, or be otherwise synchronized. See the questions I linked for more info.

Comment: There is no way you can do that. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).